# Android Studio Preference Layout Tab Completely Broken

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-preferences

I am trying to create a settings menu in Android Studio, but the design tab is completely broken.  When I drag and drop items into the screen, nothing happens.  The two existing components are from the Text tab, however, as I am not very experienced in Android, the design tab is my best friend.

I've tried restarting Android Studio, and nothing.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks.

[image: Where are my preferences?]

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat />
    <EditTextPreference />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: did u try to restart and build your app

Comment: please post the xml of the layout and any errors you may see as well.

Comment: @HemalHerath Did both, didn't work

Comment: @parkgrrr updated OP

Comment: You are right, you can see it in the designer if you have it configured correctly.  What is the file path of your xml?  You don't see any errors?

Comment: @parkgrrr `app/res/xml/xml_file.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Using the Text tab (now the Code tab) is more useful for PreferenceScreen. I think if you add `android:title=""` to all your defined Preference children in the XML file, it will show up.